# See if file path is inside a directory

Tags: c#, .net

How can I check whether a path to a file that doesn't necessarily exists points to a location inside a particular directory? Say I have a method:

```
bool IsInside(string path, string folder)
{
    //...
}
```

Then, if I call it like:

```
IsInside("C:\\Users\\Dude\\Hi", "C:\\Users\\Dude\\Hi\\SubFolder\\SubSubFolder\\tile.txt")
```

should return `true` (note the sub folder), but if I call it like:

```
IsInside("C:\\Users\\Dude\\Hi", "C:\\Users\\Dude\\BadFolder\\SubFolder\\SubSubFolder\\tile.txt")
```

should return false. The only thing I can think of right now is using string's `StartsWith`, but sounds kinda hacky to me. I haven't found a native .NET method that would check this either.

Comment: Is this dumb or does this include things like links.

Comment: no this is only for local paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [`string.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) method. If you use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) with the [StringComparison enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) it should give you the result you need.

From above link:

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of one or more characters, or the first occurrence of a string, within this string. The method returns -1 if the character or string is not found in this instance.

```
bool IsInside(string folder, string path)
{
   if (path.IndexOf(folder,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

Comment: But then this is case sensitive. I wonder if there is a way to get some kind of standardized value for a path such that the same path will always be represented as the same string.

Comment: @JuanLuisSoldi in that case you can use a StringComparison enumeration. I will make an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to handle relative paths (../../someFile.txt)?  Something like this would work:

```
private bool IsInside(DirectoryInfo path, DirectoryInfo folder)
{
    if (path.Parent == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (String.Equals(path.Parent.FullName, folder.FullName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return IsInside(path.Parent, folder);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\Dude\\Hi");
DirectoryInfo path = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\Dude\\Hi\\SubFolder\\SubSubFolder\\tile.txt");

bool result = IsInside(path, folder);
```